# MRTG similar software using SNMP4J?

Tags: snmp4j

I want to build a tool similar to MRTG that checks a group of Snmp devices and maintains a database of the net bandwidth usage of the devices with time and peak usage at an hour interval.

I have to build this using java and probably SNMP4J API. Does anyone know any detailed tutorial or example on how to start this ?

The tools basically requires to GET command of SNMP. Where can I find a piece of code or documentation that will be helpful to build this tool ?

Answer (score 1):

Such a "tool" already exists and is open source. It is called [OpenNMS](http://www.opennms.org/).